# Two-Way Data Binding with React and Meteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Is there another way of writing this? By the way, this works perfectly but I feel it could be written better:

```
Profile = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      currentUser: Meteor.user(),
    };
  },
  getInitialState(){
   // we add an if statement to prevent undefined errors
   // could this be written elsewhere?
    if (Meteor.user().profile) {
      this.profile =  Meteor.user().profile;
    } else {
      this.profile =  '';
    };
     return { firstname: this.profile.firstname };
   },

   ...
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an ES6 class, which is the way recommended when working with Meteor (ecmascript package has you covered). Also, you don't need to use Meteor.user() outside `getMeteorData()` method.

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){ super(props); }

  mixins: [ReactMeteorData]

  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      user: Meteor.user(),
    };
  }

  getInitialState(){    

    return { 
      firstname: this.data.user && this.data.user.profile.firstname 
    }        
  }
}
```